# Exercise involving a $r$-transitive permutation group of a finite set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Let $\Gamma$ be a $r$-transitive group of permutations of a set $E$
>   with $n$ elements. Let $\sigma\in\Gamma$ be a permutation of $E$ such
>   that $\sigma\ne id_E$ such that $$|\{x\in E\ |\ \sigma(x)=x\}|=n-s.$$
>   If $s>r$, show that there exists a permutation $\tau\in\Gamma$ such
>   that $\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\ne id_E$ and $$|\{x\in E\ |\
>  \tau(x)=x\}|\ge n-2(s-r+1).$$

This exercise comes with the following hint: "*use the decomposition of $\sigma$ into its component cycles*".

Let $\langle\sigma\rangle$ be the subgroup generated by $\sigma$ and lets $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of $\langle\sigma\rangle$-orbits not consisting of a single element. For $Y\in \mathcal{S}$, let $\zeta_Y(x)=\sigma(x)$ if $x\in Y$ and $\zeta_Y(x)=x$ if $x\not\in Y$. The family of cycles $(\zeta_Y)_{Y\in\mathcal{S}}$ is the unique family such that
$$\sigma=\prod_{Y\in\mathcal{S}}\zeta_Y$$
and $\text{supp}(Y)\cap\text{supp}(Y')=\emptyset$ for all $Y\ne Y'\in\mathcal{S}$. I am not sure how to use this cycle decomposition to construct $\tau$.

**Edit: some deductions**

We can easily deduce that $|\{x\in E\ |\ \sigma(x)\ne x\}|=s$ and that
$$\{x\in E\ |\ \sigma(x)\ne x\}= \bigcup_{Y\in\mathcal{S}} Y.$$
Since $s>r$ there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k\ne 0$ and $s=r+k$. At this point I most likely have to utilize the assumption of $r$-transitivity.

Comment: Where did you find this exercise? Having a hint implies that it's from some textbook or something.

Comment: Bourbaki Algebra p.143 exercise 15. This is only the first part of exercise 15.

Comment: I think this can be false when $r=1$ and $s=n$. because we could have $\sigma \in Z(G)$ and then clearly no such $\tau$ exists. Have you left out some assumptions?

Comment: There are other counterexamples with $r=1$, such as $G = C_2 \wr C_3 = \langle (1,2),(1,3,5)(2,4,6) \rangle$ and $\sigma =(1,2)$ with $s=2$. I think you need to assume that $r \ge 2$.